# Doctrine ManyToMany distinction field - possible?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to achieve a subscription model that can be applied to multiple entities using a single table/class with Doctrine 2. See explanation by example below.

**Schema (yml):**

```
User:
  type: entity
  table: users
  id: int
  name: string

Subscription:
  type: entity
  table: subscriptions
  id: int
  object_type: string
  object_id: int
  user_id: int

Feature:
  type: entity
  table: features
  id: int
  name: string
  manyToMany:
    subscribers:
      targetEntity: User
      joinTable:
        name: subscriptions
        joinColumns:
          object_id:
            referencedColumnName: id

Issue:
  type: entity
  table: issues
  id: int
  subject: string
  manyToMany:
    subscribers:
      targetEntity: User
      joinTable:
        name: subscriptions
        joinColumns:
          object_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
```

The table data would look something like this:

```
users:
| id | name |
| 1  | John |
| 2  | Joe  |

features:
| id | name      |
| 1  | Feature A |
| 2  | Feature B |

issues:
| id | subject |
| 1  | Issue 1 |
| 2  | Issue 2 |

subscriptions:
| id | object_type | object_id | user_id
| 1  | feature     | 1         | 1        <- John is subscribed to Feature A
| 2  | issue       | 1         | 1        <- John is subscribed to Issue 1
```

What I'd expected to have is an additional 'distinction' field that I can have in the model's manyToMany relation for example:

```
manyToMany:
  subscribers:
    targetEntity: User
    joinTable:
      name: subscriptions
      joinColumns:
        object_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
        object_type:
          value: feature
```

I know that the latter soultion doesn't exist in doctrine, however I'd be curious how would you solve this situation?

The idea would be to dynamically extend this subscription "trait" to other entities as well (eg. Project, Team, etc)

Do I have to introduce separate tables for all the subscriptions like `feature_subscribers` and `issue_subscribers`.. and so on, or is there a more elegant way?

**UPDATE:**

I don't want to know from the Subscription side the target object's type. I'm only looking for to get the subscribers (collection of `User`) from entities (Feature, Issue, etc).

Comment: Is this the case maybe where Mapped Superclasses come up?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm only looking for to get the subscribers (collection of User) from entities (Feature, Issue, etc)." ... are you looking for the query to lookup all users for issues/features? please clarify :)

Comment: I mean that I won't query subscriptions for objects of different types. Ie I'm not willing to use Doctrine to automagically fetch the proper object/entity (like Issue or Feature) based on a Subscription object.

What I'm looking for to get a list of subscribed users from a Feature or Issue object like `$feature->getSubscribers()` or `$issue->getSubscribers()`

Comment: you would normally put such a method into your subscription repository  ... something like `$subscriptionRepository->getSubscribersForObject($issue)`

Comment: That's it! Add as new answer and I'll accept it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this subscription table layout by using [single table inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) with a discriminator map. ( see [this blog post](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2012/03/27/table-inheritance-with-doctrine.htm) for an example )

Lets say your subscription-manager service's `subscribe(User $user, SubscriptionObject $object)` method receives a user object and an object to subscribe to ( feature or issue).

Now the subscription-manager creates either a `IssueSubscription` or `FeatureSubscription` object and persists it. This way doctrine would save the `object_type` correctly depending on your discriminator-map.

Finally you'd have to add a listener/subscriber that dynamically adjusts the relation mapping ( relation to Issue or Feature ) of your ***Subscription object in order to have the foreign key always saved to `object_id`.

A quicker way might be just using IssueSubscription->Issue and FeatureSubscription->Feature relation mappings ending in a table layout like this:

```
subscriptions:
| id | object_type | feature_id | issue_id  | user_id
| 1  | feature     | 1          | NULL      | 1 
| 2  | issue       | NULL       | 1         | 1
```

... then adding a simple `getObject()` method to your `BaseSubscription` like `return ( $this->feature != null ) ? $this->feature : $this->issue;` would ommit the need for the listener.

Comment: Thank you nifr. This way however the Subscription class must know of every possible entity using him in advance, as they have to be put in the DiscriminatorMap. The idea would be the opposite: to create a plugin-like architecture, so that new entities can say "hello I am entity 'xyz' and users can subscribe to me" without modifying the Subscription class/table.

Comment: this could be achieved using a listener that creates the discriminator mapping on the fly i.e. using the returned string of the object to subscribe's `getDiscriminatorIdentifier()` method. got me?

Comment: Yes, I think I do :) So I guess Doctrine has an API for manipulating discriminator maps on the fly.

Comment: http://thoughtsofthree.com/2011/04/defining-discriminator-maps-at-child-level-in-doctrine-2-0/

Comment: Oh that's freakin' cool; you even gave me two possible answers